# Como configurar um timer no Android Studio para executar tarefas em intervalos constantes?

Tags: java, android, funções, time

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples com Android Studio e preciso criar um timer para executar alguns métodos a cada 1 segundo.

Tentei da seguinte forma mas não deu certo:

```
int delay = 1000;
int interval = 1000;
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // métodos ...
        }
    }, delay, interval);
```

Quando o timer é ativado pela primeira vez, ocorre erro fatal fechando a aplicação.

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá? Que código está a executar dentro do método `run()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo fortemente que utilize a classe `Handler` pois no android, qualquer processo um pouco demorado e que não esteja em uma Thread será considerado um travamento e o será encerrado com um erro crítico. Não tenho certeza, mas até onde eu sei a classe Times não está presente no Android. Segue a melhor solução:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Nome_da_Classe extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Handler handler = new Handler(); //contador de tempo
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1500); //o exemplo 2000 = 2 segundos

 }

@Override
    public void run() {

        //Esse métedo será execultado a cada período, ponha aqui a sua lógica 

    } 

}
```

Observe que pus alguns códigos da classe para você poder observar onde cada linha de código se encontra.
Isso funciona, qualquer problema ou dúvida é só perguntar!

Comment: Usando o Handler eu consigo que seja executado uma ação depois de um determinado tempo. Mas ela não está se repetindo assim como eu preciso

Comment: Não colega, o Handler irá repetir a cada período indefinidamente, ou seja, até que você o pare. Utilizo o tempo todo no Android e é exatamente assim que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void Timer(){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Task task = new Task();

        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Timer();
    }

    class Task extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Metodos
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// vamos no mais importante, a classe Timer tem um metodo chamado schedule (Agendar), //onde esse método recebe o (TimerTask,long delay, long timesinmillis);

```
public void inicializaTimer() {

    this.mCalendarDateFirst.setTimeInMillis(mTime);

     this.mCalendarDateFirst.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);

     String data = this.mCalendarDateFirst.getTime().toString();

    this.startaThread();

   this.mTimer.schedule(this.mTimerTask, mCalendarDateFirst.getTime(), 1000);
}



  public void startaThread() {

    this.mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
```

//hoje no android utilizando o run do timetask e o metodo do handle o post.
caso queira saber mais consulta na documentação do android "processos e encadeamento".

```
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (stop) {
                        mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, ServicoNotificacaoBackGround.class));
                    } else {
                        mCalendarAtual.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        mCalendarHorario.setTimeInMillis(mTime);

                        Log.i("Data String", "Time " + mCalendarHorario.getTime().toString());
                        Log.i("Data String 2", "Time " + mCalendarAtual.getTime().toString());
                        if (mCalendarHorario.getTime().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(mCalendarAtual.getTime().toString())) {                   
                            stop = true;
                        }
                Toast.makeText(ExampleService.this, "Foi ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.d("ExampleService", "Serviço Executando com Sucesso");

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };         
}
```

esse é um exemplo que poderia ser a solução do problema, ou seja, executando de 1 em 1 segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema, o timerTask fechava meu frame depois de algumas vezes...
o que resolveu foi cancelar o timer ao executar a tarefa, e iniciar novamente ao terminar!

```
timer = new Timer();

TAREFA = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // metodo aqui
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TAREFA, 0, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito bem, o que resolveu pra mim,foi cancelar o timer antes da execução do metodo, e startar após a execução:

```
timer = new Timer();
TAREFA = new TimerTask() { @Override public void run() {
    timer.cancel();
    // metodo aqui
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TAREFA, 0, 2500);
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TAREFA, 0, 2500);
```